# NMinimize cannot be used within RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, regions

My version of Mathematica (11.1) apparently cannot do NMinimize within RegionPlot. It did work before (!) my last software update.

Here is an example from user GioMott having the same (unanswered) problem:

```
RegionPlot[
 First@NMinimize[1 + a t + b t^2, t] > 0, {a, 0, 3}, {b, 0, 4}]
```

This produce a long list of error messages.

Comment: If you ask the same question simultaneously on multiple forums you should note that in your question:  https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1827860.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to separate `NMinimize`

```
j[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := First@NMinimize[1 + a t+ b t^2 , t]
```

but

```
RegionPlot[j[a, b] >= 0, {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 4}]
(*Show::gtype: Success is not a type of graphics. ... *)
```

gives several error messages.

As a workaround you might try

```
zw = Flatten[Table[{a, b, j[a, b]}, {a, 0, 3, .1},{b, 0, 4, .1}], 1]
(*message: NMinimize::ubnd: The problem is unbounded.*)

Show[Graphics[{Point[Select[zw, #[[3]] > 0 &][[All,{1, 2}]]]}],Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {a, b}]
```

[image]